# A programming puzzle without code

Tags: pattern, visual, strategy

The goal of this puzzle is to find a sequence of max 5 commands that will move the triangle through the maze and visit **all** colored squares.

Three types of commands can be used:

- F0 makes the sequence start over.
- The arrows (↑, ↱, ↰) move the triangle (forward) or make it change orientation (clockwise, anti-clockwise).
- Xs change the color of the square the triangle is in to the color of the X.

Each command can (but does not need to) have a color. A colored command is only executed if the triangle is in a square of the same color.

Demonstration of the mechanics and example puzzles [here](https://www.turingpuzzles.com/index/?ref=g5tez9).

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the site.

[image: A programming puzzle without code]

Comment: We are not allowed to visit gray square, cmiiw?

Comment: @athin only blue, green, and red squares can be visited. Attempting to visit a grey square is not allowed.

Comment: Nice puzzle concept. If you are affiliated with the site in question, please (take some credit! and) let us know that  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets try it in natural language

> Start: Turn right, Forward, Turn left if blue, Forward, restart

or abbreviated

> F0: R, F, L(blue), F, F0